# Is there a way to tell if a composite number is the product of a (1x9) or a (3x3) factors

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The $(1\times 9)$ and $(3 \times3)$ here refer only to the last digit of the factors. For example can we tell if $1159=19 \times 61$ is a $(1 \times 9)$ product without factoring it.

We want to be able to distinguish between composite integers having the same last digit (like $1159=19 \times 61$ and $1339=13 \times 103$) without factoring them.

Is there a simple test to determine the last digit of the factors given a composite integer?

Comment: What about numbers like $99=3 \times 33 = 9 \times 11$? Or are you only interested in numbers that are the product of two primes?

Comment: @micah, I am interested in all numbers. I just provided two examples for clarification. There are three ways to produce a number with last digit of 9 and they are (1x9), (3x3) and (7x7) and I am looking for a way to tell which is which without factoring the number.

Comment: The point is, these aren't exclusive categories. What do you want the result to be for numbers that fall into more than one of them?

Comment: can you explain why you think they aren't exclusive categories. Are there more than 3 ways to get a composite number with a last digit of 9? It shouldn't matter if we consider a number like (3x9)x7=(3x7)x9. It can be considered as a (7x7) number or a (1x9). A test, if there is one, will tell us that it can be both.
I have no idea what the result would be so I can't answer you question.